# What is a Mediocre Word™?

Tags: wordplay, pattern, word-property, english

*This puzzle is based off and inspired by the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) and [What is a Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) and their spin-off [What is a Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.*

---

## Main puzzle:

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **mediocre** word.
Here is a list of examples:

| Mediocre Words™ | Non-Mediocre Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| LACE | FRILL |
| NIT | LOUSE |
| PI | PHI |
| MODE | SCALE |
| AMELIO | FRANCISCO |
| I | YOU |
| CAST | CREW |
| GENE | EXON |
| TEMPE | TUCSON |
| PRO-LIFE | PRO-CHOICE |
| KA | AKH |

In CSV format:

```
Mediocre Words™,Non-Mediocre Words™
LACE,FRILL
PI,PHI
AMELIO,FRANCISCO
NIT,LOUSE
I,YOU
MODE,SCALE
CAST,CREW
GENE,EXON
TEMPE,TUCSON
PRO-LIFE,PRO-CHOICE
KA,AKH
```

What is the rule to tell whether a word is a Mediocre Word™ or not? Why is it called a Mediocre Word™?

(Note that each word can be tested for whether it is a Mediocre Word™ on its own, without looking at any of the other words in the list of examples.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A Mediocre Word is

> a word that forms another word when the letters RATE are appended to the end.

For example:

> LACERATE, NITRATE, PIRATE, MODERATE, AMELIORATE, IRATE, CASTRATE, GENERATE, TEMPERATE, PROLIFERATE, and KARATE are all valid English words.
>
>  FRILLRATE, LOUSERATE, etc. are not English words.

The connection with the title is:

> mediocre could be a synonym for "second-rate", and each of the Mediocre Words has "rate" as the second part of the word.

Comment: Yes! Now why is it called a Mediocre Word?

Comment: Is it because of “moderate”?

Comment: @SeptaCube spoilers and no

Comment: I think the link with the title you're currently missing is rot13('frpbaq engr' nf 'engr' pna or hfrq nf gur 'frpbaq' unys bs rnpu jbeq, naq 'frpbaq engr' zrnaf 'zrqvbper')

Comment: @Stiv that's exactly it!

Comment: But how would you even figure this out?